# Second partial derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

x = $4e^t$  and  y = 3t.
Suppose that  
$f_x(4, 0)$ = 1,  
$f_y(4, 0)$ = 1,

Find  $d^$/$dt$

when t = 0.

I used the product rule and found a long expression for the second derivative, I substituted the numbers into the equation but I keep getting 71. Can someone show me where I messed up? or show how to get the right solution?

[Expression I got after using product rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs5zD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\\
\frac{d^2 h}{d t^2}=(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t})^2+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2})+(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^2+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2})+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=4e^t\\
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t}=4e^t\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=3\\
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}=0$

Now all you have to do is insert $t=0$. Hopefully that makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it!!!